# How to migrate NiFi Processor's cluster-state

Tags: apache-nifi

A case I've faced with is the following: in our workflow all developers make changes on dev-environment and commit modified Processor Group `PG` by exporting it as XML template. The other guys delete an old-working `PG` and install the new one `PG` from this template on test(prod)-environment.

I tried to save a state of Statefull processors of this `PG` to restore it after such 'brute-reinstall'. And this step is done easy with a nice NiFi REST API:

```
/nifi-api/processors/{id}/state   Gets the state for a processor
```

And then I need to put it back. Suppose that finding corresponding Porcessors GUIDs already done - ok, guids are new but this 'seems' not as a problem. I can't put state back:

I've found (by investigating `TestAbstractListProcessor.java` particularly) that if I have a Processor GUID and put a file `conf/state/<proc-guid>` with special-formatted content like: `param={json-params}` then after the First (and only first) processor run it `migrates` its state from this file (and then deletes it). The second option I've found is to directly put CLUSTER state (I'm only care of CLUSTER statefull Processors) into Zookeeper path `/nifi/components/<guid>`.

But there is a problem - this is not work at all after changing a Processors properties. So I even can not create a Processor, modify (**initial** set) its state, supply with `conf/state/<proc-guid>` (or set `/nifi/components/<guid>`) and first-run. The code (in `AbstractListProcessor.java` for example) sees that there some property-changes happend, and **discards** the state already read.

How do I migrate CLUSTE state of NiFi processor properly in a case of NiFi Processors Group upgrade? For some reasons (which I didn't understand yet) NiFi REST API allows only `get` and `clear` Processors state, but not to `set` it:

```
/nifi-api/processors/{id}/state/clear-requests   Clears the state for a processor
But there is no set-state API
```

Comment: Strongly recommend to use nifi-registry.

Comment: Yes if use nifi-registry then you won't need to delete PGs to upgrade them, which means you won't lose the state.